# Passing multiple parameters in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How can I pass multiple parameters from excel while it comes under BodyData?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Just add your variables inside `${}` for example for emailIdName and emailIdValue use:

```
{"${emailIdName ": "${emailIdValue}"}
```

You can add User Parameters as Pre Processor and add to different variable the full Body Data, e.g. Name: bodyData, USER_1:

```
{"${emailIdName ": "${emailIdValue}"}
```

and then use `${bodyData}` inside Body Data

Comment: Thank you sir ,,Is it is possible to convert body Data as parameter once after running the script? or how i can get those body data in parameter column?

Comment: Add to my answer how to add Body Data as parameter